How to remove the top 3% of values in SQL
I have this challenge of pulling a bunch of sales data together and filtereing it out and removing the top 3% of values.
This is my SQL so far, i have allready filtered it in DESC order, i now need to hide / remove the top 3% of values.
SELECT
  prod."ColumnA" AS "ColumnA",
  COUNT(items."ColumnB") AS "ColumnC"
FROM "Table1" AS items
LEFT JOIN "Table2" AS prod ON items."ColumnD" = prod."ColumnE"
LEFT JOIN "Table3" AS sales ON items."ColumnF" = sales."ColumnG"
WHERE sales."ColumnH" >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 150 DAY)
  AND prod."ColumnA" != 'Value1'
  AND prod."ColumnA" != 'Value2'
  AND prod."ColumnA" != 'Value3'
GROUP BY prod."ColumnA"
ORDER BY "ColumnC" DESC;

I have looked into some standard methods and read through some docs but couldnt find something similar to my case.
I have tried using PERCENT_RANK(), however this hasnt worked. Producing this error in my enviroment
You can use the tabular functions in SELECT and ORDER BY clauses only
This is the SQL i included aftermy GROUP BY
HAVING PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(items."Id") DESC) <= 0.97

Which dbms are you actually using? I doubt the above query will run on more than one of the ones you've tagged.

I've removed the conflicting tags; you'll need to [edit] your question to (re)tag the RDBMS you are really using.

You could run 2 queries, one to get the count of rows, then multiply that by the 3%/.03, to get a number.  Then user that variable value from the calculation and select TOP using the variable for the number of rows.  Re-read the question and you need to remove the top 3%.  So do the same but multiply by .97 to get the count you want to keep then reverse the order by and you will select the top 97% you want.

You don't specify SQL product, but if SQL Server, SELECT TOP 97 PERCENT...

Apologies, for not mentioning. This query is being ran in Zoho Analytics where mutliple data sources are being pooled into. Ive tried to find waht dbms they run but ive been told MySQL & "Standard Select query".
